# Gradle is failing a project dependency as it cannot add jar file to itself

Tags: java, gradle, jar

I am creating a new gradle build for some existing code. I am looking at the first two projects - common and database. database is dependent on common.

Both have a shared list of jar files which is being correctly added as a dependency from a shared root build.gradle. The common code is compiled correctly and without problem.

The issue I have is adding a dependency to common from database causes gradle to try and add the common.jar file to itself, filling up the hard drive until it ultimately crashes.

I have tried setting the dependency in a build.gradle in the database folder, and adding it in the root build.gradle using project(":database"), and both have the same problem.

I cannot change the "src" folder as these are existing projects, and the application that uses them understands the given structure:
common
common\src
common\src\common
common\src\common\MyFile.java
database
database\src
database\src\database
database\src\database\MyDatabase.java
database\src\database\example\DatabaseExample.java
etc

```
subprojects {

    apply plugin: "java"

    sourceSets {
        main {
            java.srcDirs = files("src")
            java.outputDir = file("build")
        }
    } 

    dependencies {
        implementation files(
            fileTree("${binDir}") { include("java*.jar") },
            "${binDir}/blah/blah_core.jar",
            <etc - none of them are common.jar>
        )
    }
}

project(":database") {
    dependencies {
        implementation project(":common")
    }
}
```

12:39:38.649 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter] FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
12:39:38.650 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]
12:39:38.651 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter] * What went wrong:
12:39:38.651 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter] Execution failed for task ':common:jar'.
12:39:38.651 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter] > Could not add file 'C:\Code\Git\gradle\common\build\libs\common.jar' to ZIP 'C:\Code\Git\gradle\common\build\libs\common.jar'.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone in the future; the issue was

```
            java.outputDir = file("build")
```

Removing this and the build started working as expected